# How continue with this proof?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to proof the following statement:

$7+6 \cdot (7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^n) = 7^{n+1}$

I try the next:
$n=k$

$7+6 \cdot (7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^k) = 7^{k+1}$

$7+6 \cdot (7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^k)-7 = 7^{k+1}-7$

$\frac{6 \cdot (7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^k)}{6} = \frac{7^{k+1}-7}{6}$

$7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^k = \frac{7^{k+1}-7}{6}$

$n=k+1$

$7+7^1+7^2+\dots+7^k+7^{k+1} = \frac{7^{k+2}-7}{6}$

Proof:

$\frac{7^{k+1}-7}{6}+7^{k+1} = \frac{7^{k+2}-7}{6}$

$\frac{7^{k+1}-7+6\cdot7^{k+1}}{6}$

Any idea?

Comment: Without induction, there is a much easier proof just using the $7$-adic expansion of $7^{n+1}-1$.

Comment: HINT , $6=7-1$ then use the expansion of $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$ where $x=7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a proof, so here's proof by induction.

Your statement is equivalent to:

$$6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n 7^k = 7^{n+1} - 7.$$

This is true for $n=1$:

$$6 \cdot 7 = 7^2 - 7.$$

Now look at the $n+1$ case:

$$6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 7^k = \left[6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} 7^k\right] + 6 \cdot 7^{n+1} \\ = 7^{n+1} - 7 + 6 \cdot 7^{n+1} \\= 7 \cdot 7^{n+1} - 7 \\= 7^{n+2} - 7.$$

I invoked the inductive assumption on the second line.

Comment: how convert $6*7^{n+1} in 7*7^{n+1}$

Comment: $6 \cdot 7^{n+1} + 1 \cdot 7^{n+1} = 7 \cdot 7^{n+1} = 7^{n+2}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence:

$$7+6\left(7+7^2+\ldots+7^n\right)=7+6\frac{7-7^{n+1}}{1-7}=7-7+7^{n+1}=7^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to demonstrate by induction that
$$ 
7 + 6 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n\,} } \right) = 7^{\,n + 1\,}  
$$
Now, that's true for $n=1$ 
$$ 
\begin{gathered} 
  n = 1 \hfill \\ 
  7 + 6 \cdot \left( 7 \right) = 7 \cdot \left( {6 + 1} \right) = 7^{\,2\,}  \hfill \\  
\end{gathered}  
$$
and we want to demonstrate that if it is valid for $n$ it is also valid for $n+1$.
So we take our identity, multiply both sides by $7$, do some massage 
$$ 
\begin{gathered} 
  n \to n + 1 \hfill \\ 
  7 + 6 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n\,} } \right) = 7^{\,n + 1\,}  \hfill \\ 
  7 \cdot \left( {7 + 6 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n\,} } \right)} \right) = 7 \cdot 7^{\,n + 1\,}  = 7^{\,n + 2\,}  \hfill \\ 
  \left( {7 \cdot 7 + 6 \cdot 7 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n\,} } \right)} \right) = 7^{\,n + 2\,}  \hfill \\ 
  \left( {7 \cdot \left( {6 + 1} \right) + 6 \cdot 7 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n\,} } \right)} \right) = 7^{\,n + 2\,}  \hfill \\ 
  \left( {7 + 6 \cdot 7 + 6 \cdot \left( {7^{\,2\,}  + 7^{\,3\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n + 1\,} } \right)} \right) = 7^{\,n + 2\,}  \hfill \\ 
  \left( {7 + 6 \cdot \left( {7 + 7^{\,2\,}  + 7^{\,3\,}  +  \cdots  + 7^{\,n + 1\,} } \right)} \right) = 7^{\,n + 2\,}  \hfill \\  
\end{gathered}  
$$
and get the demonstration